# order bar plots in facet grid in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet-grid, grouped-bar-chart

I have a barchart and I want to order the bars and calculate percentage of changes from one bar to another and show on the plot.
I used factors and tried different methods and everything on `stackoverflow`, but it gives me all sorts of errors. I managed to order the legend in terms of colors but the bar colours does not have the same order.

and here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

data$Active_period  <- factor(data$Active_period,levels = c("study_year","last_year", "this_year"))
fct_rev(data$Active_period)

ggplot(data, aes(count, Name, fill = Active_period)) +
geom_col(width = 0.8, position = position_dodge2(width = 0.8, preserve = "single"))+
facet_grid(Time ~ site)+
scale_fill_manual(name = " ",values = c("study_year" ="#5d5c5c", "this_year" ="#4475aa", 
"last_year" = "#333239"),limits = c("study_year","last_year", "this_year"))+
theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
          axis.text = element_text(size = 11), 
          axis.title = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
          strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
          strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 13)))
```

Here is my data:

```
Name | Active_period| site |Time | count
A | Last_year| north| mornings |10
A | Last_year| south| mornings |20
A | Last_year| north| evenings|45
A | Last_year| south| evenings|35
A | this_year| north| mornings |80
A | this_year| south| mornings |60
A | this_year| north| evenings|95
A | this_year| south| evenings|120
A | study_year| north| mornings |100
A | study_year| south| mornings |400
A | study_year| north| evenings|220
A | study_year| south| evenings|32
B | Last_year| north| mornings |10
B | Last_year| south| mornings |45
B | Last_year| north| evenings|25
B | Last_year| south| evenings|20
B | this_year| north| mornings |300
B | this_year| south| mornings |250
B | this_year| north| evenings|140
B | this_year| south| evenings|20
B | study_year| north| mornings |10
B | study_year| south| mornings |20
B | study_year| north| evenings|10
B | study_year| south| evenings|20
```

Comment: The bar colours do have the same order as the legend, at least they do when I run your code. Is it only the percent changes that are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.
First, I create a custom theme so that the problem code is simpler. This is not really part of the question and it can be defined before the answer.

```r
theme_so_q77804382 <- function(){ 
  theme_grey(base_size = 10) %+replace%
    theme(
      legend.position = "bottom", 
      axis.text = element_text(size = 11), 
      axis.title = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
      strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
      strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12, angle = -90),
      plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 13)
    )
}
```

---

## The plot

The plot is a horizontal bars plot of counts by name so instead of defining the y axis as the names axis, the recommended way is to define the independent variable in the x axis as usual and then reverse with `coord_flip`.

Now the problem.

- first, coerce `Active_period` to factor;
- then, compute the percentage changes grouped by `Name`, `site` and `Time`;
- now that we have the changes from base level `study_year`, reverse the factor levels to have the plot as asked.

Then just plot it, with the percentages plotted with `geom_text`. The text must also be grouped and since `fill` is not a `geom_text` aesthetic, use `group = Active_period`. Play a little with `hjust` in order to have the minus signs visible whenever the changes are negative.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

data$Active_period[data$Active_period == "Last_year"] <- "last_year"

data %>%
  mutate(Active_period = factor(Active_period,levels = c("study_year","last_year", "this_year"))) %>%
  group_by(Name, site, Time) %>%
  arrange(Active_period) %>%
  mutate(perc = scales::percent(c(0, diff(count))/dplyr::lag(count, default  = 1))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Active_period = forcats::fct_rev(Active_period)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Name, count, fill = Active_period)) +
  geom_col(
    width = 0.8, 
    position = position_dodge2(width = 0.8, preserve = "single")
  ) +
  geom_text(
    position = position_dodge2(width = 0.8, preserve = "single"),
    aes(label = perc, group = Active_period),
    hjust = -0.2
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = " ", 
    values = c(study_year ="#5d5c5c", this_year = "#4475aa", last_year = "#333239"),
    limits = c("study_year","last_year", "this_year")
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(Time ~ site) +
  theme_so_q77804382()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

In order to remove the `"0%"` from the first bars, change the dplyr pipe to

```
data %>%
  mutate(Active_period = factor(Active_period,levels = c("study_year","last_year", "this_year"))) %>%
  group_by(Name, site, Time) %>%
  arrange(Active_period) %>%
  mutate(
    perc = scales::percent(c(0, diff(count))/dplyr::lag(count, default  = 1)),
    perc = c("", perc[-1L])
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Active_period = forcats::fct_rev(Active_period)) %>%
```

The change that removes the number is in the 2nd `mutate`.

Comment: thanks a lot, the answer was awesome and there are lots of thing to learn from your answer. just, how I can remove the 0% from the first bar?

Comment: I tried to align the percentages number  with the right axis of each plot instead of each bar. but it would not work!

Comment: @GeoBeez What have you tried, can you edit the question with that code?

Comment: thanks for answering my question. I asked my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77808573/keep-only-some-of-the-bar-labels-on-the-right-end-side-of-the-plot-r ; and in the plot I showed what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

In your data you use **L**ast_year while in your factor levels you use  **l**ast_year. The levels are **case sensitive**. Once, fixed (I fixed it in the data) the plot looks as follows:

### Data

```r
d <- readr::read_delim(
"Name|Active_period|site|Time|count
A|Last_year|north|mornings|10
A|Last_year|south|mornings|20
A|Last_year|north|evenings|45
A|Last_year|south|evenings|35
A|this_year|north|mornings|80
A|this_year|south|mornings|60
A|this_year|north|evenings|95
A|this_year|south|evenings|120
A|study_year|north|mornings|100
A|study_year|south|mornings|400
A|study_year|north|evenings|220
A|study_year|south|evenings|32
B|Last_year|north|mornings|10
B|Last_year|south|mornings|45
B|Last_year|north|evenings|25
B|Last_year|south|evenings|20
B|this_year|north|mornings|300
B|this_year|south|mornings|250
B|this_year|north|evenings|140
B|this_year|south|evenings|20
B|study_year|north|mornings|10
B|study_year|south|mornings|20
B|study_year|north|evenings|10
B|study_year|south|evenings|20", delim = "|", col_types = "ffffi")
```

### Code

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

## Note: I replace Last_year by last_year in the data
## alternatively you could also adapt your levels
## but since all levels are lower case I felt this is more consistent
d2 <- d %>% 
  mutate(Active_period = factor(Active_period %>% 
                                  stringr::str_to_lower(),
                                levels = c("this_year", "last_year", "study_year")))

d2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(count, Name, fill = Active_period)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.8, position = position_dodge2(width = 0.8, preserve = "single"))+
  facet_grid(Time ~ site) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = " ",
                    values = c("study_year" = "#5d5c5c", "this_year" = "#4475aa", 
                               "last_year" = "#333239"),
                    limits = c("study_year", "last_year", "this_year")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 11), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 13))
```

[image: Facetted Barplot where each bar has the color as specified in the code]